# Customizing debug print format with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is it possible to see ints (and ints that are parts of dicts, lists, and tuples, etc.) as hex values when debugging with PyDev?

More broadly, is it possible to make any given data type show up the way you want in the variable display tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyDev Debugger simply uses the `repr()` function to show the values. So if overwrite the `__repr__()` function than you can change how the values are printed.

I don't think there are any other options of changing the way your variables show, although you might (not sure about that) be able to get away with overwriting the `repr()` function itself.

Comment: Specifically, that would be `repr = lambda x: hex(x) if isinstance(x, int) else repr(x)` (ignoring `long`). Adds quotes though. Use `hex(x)[1:-1]` to strip those. And keep in mind that's very very hacky.

Comment: it looks like repr is used for the flyover representation, and str is used for the Variables window.  What's up with that?

Comment: @delnan: it should be noted that for that to work, you'll probably have to overwrite `__builtin__.repr`

Comment: @K. Brafford: Not sure about that... I rarely understand some of the strange decisions that have been made in pydev ;)